# Bluetooth not working, `Bluetooth: hci0: FW download error recovery failed (-19)`

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I'm trying to connect to bluetooth headphones using `bluetoothctl` without success. Here are the logs:

from `bluetoothctl`:

```
[bluetooth]# connect 6C:D3:EE:E2:D2:D7 
Attempting to connect to 6C:D3:EE:E2:D2:D7
[CHG] Device 6C:D3:EE:E2:D2:D7 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 6C:D3:EE:E2:D2:D7 Connected: no
```

from `journalctl -p3 -e`:

```
...
<datetime> nixos kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: FW download error recovery failed (-19)
...
```

I am using bluez 1.70 on NixOS unstable. I've tried rebooting multiple times, but it didn't help. How can I resolve this issue?